# Classic ASP + IIS 7 Writing a file to a network drive

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have Classic ASP 2 websites on an Windows 2008 IIS 7 install. website1.com and website2.com.  Both are serving the same website from one folder: C:\Webs\website\

website1.com has been in operation for 6 years and in the app it can write files to a network share; \wdc\SharedFiles\assets\docs\
All the proper permissions are set as it has been reading and writing files for years.

I recently added website2.com. The website is serving from the same diretory. I need it to be able to write to that same share. The problem is, website2.com gets "Write to file failed." and "Permission Denied" errors.

How is this possible?

I even mocked up a simple test. Same error.:

```
  Dim fso, objFile
  Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile=fso.CreateTextFile("\\wdc\SharedFiles\assets\docs\test.txt")
  objFile.WriteLine("hello this is test")
  objFile.Close
  Set objFile=Nothing
  Set fso=Nothing
```

Any ideas? I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the permissions of the `\\wdc\SharedFiles\assets\docs\` directory?  Perhaps there is a special user account set up or something.

Comment: windows 2008 .... IIS 6?????, i'm almost sure that it's IIS 7

Comment: Rafael, you don't believe the old crap some shops are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. So others can benefit, here it is:

1. In IIS go to the website (website2.com) node, then select "Authentication".
2. Make sure "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled and set it to a user.
3. Then with the Explorer give that user read-and-write access to the share.

Comment: very nice finding @xweb. i would give you +1000 if possible. i did also pulled my hair out during last 24 hour.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It was a time consuming process to find that solution.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will make a difference. The only difference in my code, really, is that I'm using server.mapPath to specify path.

```
path = Server.MapPath ("\")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "\" & txtFileName, 2) '2 = for Writing
f.Write(txtFileContents)
f.close
set f=nothing
```

Comment: This code isn't writing to a network drive, but to the web root (default is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot") on the same server. See examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_mappath.asp